# Getting "Unimplemented SQL generation for predicate (parentDates.date MATCHES CAST(637183491.329559, \"NSDate\"))" exception

Tags: sql, swift, xcode, core-data

I am using Core Data to try to create a journal database. I don't know enough about querying to know what I'm doing wrong.

> The parent class is Dates with a attribute of date (type Date)

> the child class is Entries with an attribute of title (type String)

> the Dates and Entries are in a One-to-Many relationship. ie. there may be multiple entries for a given date but the same entry can't be on multiple dates.

```
func loadData(){
    
    let request: NSFetchRequest<Entries> = Entries.fetchRequest()
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "parentDates.date MATCHES %@", selectedDate!.date! as CVarArg)
    request.predicate = predicate
    
    
    do{
        entryArray = try context.fetch(request)
    }catch{
        print("Error loading context, \(context)")
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}//end loadData
```

Comment: `MATCHES` is for regular expression matching, and expects a string as argument. Perhaps you simply want `"parentDates.date == %@"` ?

Comment: That was it, thank you! I'm still trying to learn the little nuances of Xcode.